# Duplicate dependency error when using webpack

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, serverless-framework, yarn-workspaces

I'm receiving the following error when running locally with webpack.

```
  Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
  directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
  relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.

  https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions

  Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
  versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
  version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
  spurious results.
```

I have added graphql to my root package.json's resolutions section (I am using workspaces)

```
{
  ...

  "resolutions": {
    ...
    "graphql": "15.5.1"
  }
}
```

I have since cleaned my cache, deleted all node_modules folders, deleted yarn.lock, and reinstalled the dependencies using yarn. However, the error persists. Additionally, there's only one version of graphql in the yarn.lock file.

I am not experiencing this issue when running index.ts locally with ts-node. Here's my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const serverlessWebpack = require('serverless-webpack')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: serverlessWebpack.lib.entries,
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: serverlessWebpack.lib.webpack ? 'development' : 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: { concatenateModules: false },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{
        from: './src/schema.graphql',
        to: './src/schema.graphql',
      }, {
        from: './prisma/schema.prisma',
        to: './src/schema.prisma',
      }]
    }),
  ],
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  stats: 'normal',
  target: 'node',
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add a graphql alias to webpack's [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).

```
alias: {
  graphql$: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/graphql/index.js'),
},
```